# Youtube Live Stream API: Resolution is Required

Tags: php, youtube-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-livestreaming-api

My code is creating the Live video on Youtube and returning the Streaming URL.
But on this point, it throws the exception: "Resolution is Required"

```
$streamsResponse = $this->youtube->liveStreams->insert('snippet,cdn', $this->live_stream, array());
$response['stream_response'] = $streamsResponse;
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation of the [`LiveStreams.insert`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/insert) API endpoint, the following [live stream properties](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#resource-representation) are required to be specified when invoking it:

> [**Request body**](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams/insert#request-body)
>
> Provide a [liveStream resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#resource) in the request body. For that resource:
>
> You must specify a value for these properties:
>
> - `snippet.title`
> - `cdn.frameRate`
> - `cdn.ingestionType`
> - `cdn.resolution`
>
> [...]

Now, you have to acknowledge that the error message has meaning, since you very likely did not passed to `LiveStreams.insert` the required [`resolution`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveStreams#cdn.resolution) property.

Your code snippet above does not show how you're constructing the object `$this->live_stream`. Fixing the Google's sample code in the file [`create_broadcast.php`](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/create_broadcast.php), you'll have to have something like the code below:

```php
// Create an object for content distribution network details for the live
// stream and specify the stream's resolution, frame rate and ingestion type.
$cdn = new Google_Service_YouTube_CdnSettings();
$cdn->setResolution("variable");
$cdn->setFrameRate("variable");
$cdn->setIngestionType('rtmp');

// Create the API request that inserts the liveStream resource.
$streamInsert = new Google_Service_YouTube_LiveStream();
$streamInsert->setSnippet($streamSnippet);
$streamInsert->setCdn($cdn);

// Execute the request and return an object that contains information
// about the new stream.
$streamsResponse = $youtube->liveStreams->insert('snippet,cdn',
    $streamInsert, array());
```